# Check if string can be made by joining smaller strings (Recursive function) in C

Tags: c

I'm studying recursion for the first time and I have problems making a recursive function works. Basically I have to see if a string (from command line) can be made by concatenating other strings. The function will return 1 if it's possible otherwise 0.

Here is the code I wrote (Sorry, I have no ground in coding and make pretty bad codes and I can't even debug it so I can't see where I am wrong).

```
int decomposition(char* argv[],char** strings,int pos,int strings_num){
int i,j,flag=0,flag2=0,tmp=pos,pos2;
char* comp;
char* comp1;
if(pos >= strlen(argv[1]))
    return 1;
for(i = 0;i<strings_num;i++){
    comp = malloc((strlen(strings[i])+1)*sizeof(char));
    comp1 = malloc((strlen(strings[i])+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(comp,"a");
    flag = 0;
    pos = tmp;
    while(strlen(strings[i])<=strlen(argv[1])-pos){
        for(j = 0;j<strlen(strings[i]);j++){
            if(strings[i][j] == argv[1][pos]){
                comp1[j] = argv[1][pos];
                pos++;
                flag = 1;
            }
            else{
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1 && strlen(comp1)>=strlen(comp)){     //comp1 must be longer than comp...if the string is "hello" between string1="he" and string2="hel" I have to choose string2
        strcpy(comp,comp1);
        pos2 = pos;                     
        flag2 = 1;
    }
}
```

Here I have problem with the recursive call...I know there's something wrong but I don't know how to correct it...

```
if(flag2 == 1){
    if(decomposition(argv,strings,pos2,strings_num)==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learning how to debug may seem tedious now but will pay off over time.

Comment: This is possibly the worst problem to practice recursion on. Are you sure that you didn't misunderstand the assignment?

Comment: I know how to debug:) Just this code can't be debugged with codeblocks I think there's some problems with the recursion...

Comment: @Let_Me_Be The assignment is just: print yes if the string can made by concatenating other strings otherwise print no. I thought that "changing" position on the string could be made with recursion. ps:Excuse my bad English but I'm italian:)

Comment: You always re-allocate new comparison strings inside the loop. That's probably not what you want. (It looks as if you wanted to use `comp` to keep the best fit so far and you lose both the allocated memory and that information on re-allocation.)

Comment: As for the assignment: Are you trying to make the first string from the remaining strings? An example might help.

Comment: What does it mean "from other strings", from what other strings?

Comment: @MOehm thanks I correct the re-allocation. The "other strings" are some strings I have read from a file. I pass all of them to the function in a char** named strings.

Comment: Example: string from command lines: "function"   strings that  are in the char**: s1="fu" s2="nct" s3="io" s4="hey" s5="n" The composition is possible because s1+s2+s3+s5 make "function". Then I only have to print: "Yes the decomposition exists"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to know whether you can make one certain string, the target, from other strings.

I'm not sure how exactly you plan your recursion (it's not very clear from your code), but it looks too complicated. You don't need any temporary storage, for example.

Your assumption that you need to pick the longest prefix is wrong, too. For example, if you want to make "helmet" from "hel", "helm" and "met", you will preclude the solution "hel·met" when you pick the longest match, "helm". The nice thing about the recursive solution is that it lets you pursue all possible avenues easily.

How does your recursion work? Scan all strings and check whether they can be a prefix for your target. If so, check whether the target minus that prefix can be made up of the strings by calling the function recursively. If no prefixes match, return false. If the target is empty after remoing the prefix, return 1.

Each recursion level keeps its local variables, so after returning from the function to the last level, you track back and start testing the original string (of that level) again.

You pass the current position in the string down to the next recursion level. That's a valid configuration, but a nice property of C strings, which really are just char arrays, is that you can easily clip off a prefix of length `len` from a string `str` by moving the pointer `len` chars to the right, provided you don't cross the null-separator. So the rest of the string is just `str + len`.

Here's a variant that takes all strings from the command line. The first string is the target string.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int decomposition(const char *target, const char *strings[], size_t n)
{
    size_t i;

    if (*target == '\0') return 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        const char *str = strings[i];
        size_t len = strlen(str);

        if (strncmp(target, str, len) == 0) {
            int res;

            res = decomposition(target + len, strings, n);
            if (res) return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: prog targer string(s) ...\n");
    } else {
        int n = decomposition(argv[1], argv + 2, argc - 2);

        printf("%s be done.\n", n ? "Can" : "Can't");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @M Oehm Got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: The code works but I have a warning on the second argument (strings) that I can solve removing const and making it just char** . Is it right? And also I have never used size_t, does it have to be size_t or can it be just a int or an unsigned int?

Comment: Sorry about the warning. You could make the second argument to `decomposition` a `char *const *strings`, but if that is too confusing, just leave out the `const`. `size_t` is an unsigned integer that usually has the same size of an pointer and is used for array dimensions and such. Many library functions use it. Your problem size will likely fit into an `int`, so you can use an `int` instead.